# If $n^c\in\mathbb N$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, then $c$ is a non-negative integer?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Supposing that a real number $c$ is given, is the following true?

"If $n^c$ is a natural number for **every** natural number $n$, then $c$ is a non-negative integer."

Though this seems true, I can't prove that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: What does it tell you if this holds for some specified natural number, for example a prime?

Comment: Maybe an inductive proof might help?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Well, nothing special. Could you tell me more about your hint?

Comment: @901301: In my opinion, it does not seem to help.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Any proof should use that $n^c$ is an integer, for **several** integers n, since otherwise the result fails.

Comment: This is an excellent question! It feels like it should have a simple proof, but I can't see any.

Comment: @Did I am aware of that. But understanding what happens when it holds for a single prime is an important first step.

Comment: Perhaps even the following is true: If $2^c$ and $3^c$ are both integers, then $c$ is an integer.

Comment: If so then for any $p,q$ we have $(p/q)^c$ is a rational, i.e. the function $f(x)=x^c$ maps the rationals into the rationals. [Only a restatement, but maybe someone will know something about such power maps, and can conclude the exponent $c$ must be a natural number.]

Comment: Maybe working with Galois extension? I mean, by contradiction if $c=a/b$, with $a,b$ coprime natural numbers and $b\geq 2$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[b]{n^a}):\mathbb{Q}]=1$ for every natural $n$...

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378130/what-is-the-set-x-in-bbb-r-mid-forall-q-in-bbb-q-qx-in-bbb-q

Comment: The problem @TonyK mentions with $2^c$ and $3^c$ is an open question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A variant of this question was asked on Mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well) by Alon Amit.  As Gerry Myerson answers, in particular, it's apparently sufficient to know that only $2^c$ and $3^c$ and $5^c$ are all integers.  It's apparently unknown whether it's sufficient to know that $2^c$ and $3^c$ are integers.

He also mentions that the original question (using $n$ instead of $2,3,5$) was actually a 1971 Putnam problem and Chris Phan provides a [link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318375?seq=6) to the solution.  (It's problem A6).

(Community wiki because I've done nothing.)

Comment: Thank you very much for great information!

Comment: @mathlove:  You're welcome!  Incidentally, since this is CW, I don't think you can award me the bounty (or maybe you can??)  In any case, I don't need it.  So if there is something you or I can do to minimize how much rep this costs you, let me know!  (For example, I have no qualms with deleting this answer and letting you write your own answer.)

Comment: Well, ok, so if I'm going to do nothing, then nothing happens, right? Is it OK to you or not?

Comment: @mathlove:  Well, I was just trying to look out for your bounty.  I am ok with anything you decide to do (or not do).

Comment: Thanks. What I said depends on my understanding that a bounty never comes back.

Comment: @mathlove:  I just read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work and it seems like I have a lot of misconceptions.  Despite this being CW, I *can* be given the bounty.  I also assumed that if you wrote the answer yourself you could award yourself the bounty.  (For something like, only losing half points).  I was clearly wrong on both counts!

Comment: I've read the following page which answers NO to the question that 'Can I award a bounty to my own answer?'

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @mathlove:  Yes, I agree with you - I was completely mistaken earlier.

Comment: Then, I'll do nothing. Anyway, thanks for your information. It did surprise me.