# Prove that if $2^x,3^x, 5^x, 7^x, 11^x ... $ are all integers then $x$ is an integer as well

Tags: functions, exponentiation, exponential-function, integers

How easy is it to prove that if $2^x,3^x, 5^x, 7^x, 11^x ... $ are integers then $x$ is an integer as well? I have read the definition of the exponent functions as given in my calculus text, and the question propped up.

Comment: Is $x$ a real number? A rational number?

Comment: @Nishant Real, obviously.

Comment: @Nishant I assume it's real.

Comment: I asked a similar question and the following page was shown. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well

Comment: Based on @mathlove's link, it's evidently enough to require that $2^x,3^x,5^x$ are integers; however, that version is evidently difficult to show. So a proof for the "bases are prime" case would indeed be neat.

Comment: @Semiclassical The fun little problem ... :O

Comment: Yes, one which is strictly speaking easier than yours! (And, reading that thread, one which no one solved when it appeared on a certain year's Putnam exam.) Hence a proof for your case would be interesting, but not necessarily very easy.

Comment: Here is [a link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/570218/1508) to the question that @mathlove posted.

Comment: @mathlove Here is the Putnam solution, https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html :) Hard really.

Comment: Curiously, if you only know that $2^x$ and $3^x$ are integers, then the question if $x$ must be an integer is open (no proof and no counter-example is known).

Answer (score -2):

Given $ 2^x $, $ 3^x $, $ 5^x $,... are integers. Now suppose $ x $ is not an integer. Suppose it is rational of the form $ p/q $ where $ gcd(p,q) = 1 $.
So $ 2^{p/q} $, $ 3^{p/q} $, ... can't be integer, since base of exponents are all prime.

Comment: But what if $x$ is irrational?

Comment: This only seems to show $x$ is not rational.

Comment: If $ x $ is irrational, irrational power of prime can't be integer.

Comment: $2^{\log(3)/\log(2)}=3$, and $\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ is definitely not rational.

Comment: We need $ x $ for all primes, means $ 2^x $, $3^x$, $ 5^x$, ....