# $n^x$ are rationals for all positive integers n, show $x$ must be an integer.

Tags: number-theory

I wanna show that if $n^x$ are rational for all positive integers n, then we may conclude $x$ is an integer. First of all, WLOG, we may assume $x$ is a real number between 0,1.
I think it suffices to show that for R={$log_p q$, where p,q are coprime positive integers bigger than 1}, then the elements of R+R contained in R must be two pairs with same p. But I stuck at proving my conjectural statement...

Comment: relevant http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378130/what-is-the-set-x-in-bbb-r-mid-forall-q-in-bbb-q-qx-in-bbb-q/378143#comment810074_378143

Comment: OK, I think I know how to prove this, by using Baker

Comment: I mean, by using Baker's theorem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem 
by Baker's thm I mean this.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused by myself... Ignore me...

Comment: @lee If you find your comment incomplete, click "edit" to modify it, instead of adding one more.

Comment: Baker's Theorem not the way to go. If you want to use a sledgehammer, the Six Exponentials Theorem will work. But this was a problem on the 1971 Putnam Exam, and can be solved without the big tools.

Comment: (Almost) duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/570218/1508.