# if $1^a,2^a,3^a,\cdots$ are integers,Prove that $a$ is also integer

Tags: number-theory

suppose that $a$ is a postive real number such that all numbers
$$1^a,2^a,3^a,\cdots$$ are integers,Prove that $a$ is also integer

This problem is 1971 Putnam competition,and the Official answer is give Using Lagrangian mean value theorem in higher mathematics, see [answer](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html),So there is no elementary practice, middle school students can do?

Comment: Did you get some progress? For example, is it clear that $a$ cannot be irrational using "middle-school" methods, for example? Unfortunately, I am not sure that you can do this in general, because how will you handle transcendental $a$ like logs and so on, which don't even fall in the middle-school domain? For example, $2^{\log_2 3} = 3$ is an integer, but the exponent is not even definable, or cannot be worked with using middle-school methods.

Comment: Also, please copy the official solution itself onto your question for completeness. (Follow on : thank you for doing that! As I mentioned earlier, it is difficult to handle log-type exponents without appealing to calculus. For one,we cannot even work with $a^b$ without using calculus).

Comment: The Putnam is, and has always been, a contest for university students. Calculus knowledge is expected for all test takers, and is fair game for even the easiest Putnam problems.

Comment: But it is said can use middle students methods to solve it,so I ask it

Comment: @inequality Who stated "it is said" that middle students are able to solve it?

Comment: FYI, I think "If $2^{a}, 3^{a}$ are integers, then $a$ is also an integer" is an open problem.

Comment: @SeewooLee Note the OP provided a link to a solution at [Putnam 1971/A6 solution](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol716.html).

Comment: @JohnOmielan I know, I just want to say that the stronger problem is an open problem.

Comment: @inequality Please refer me to whoever called this a middle school problem! It is astounding that people should even expect to know calculus at the middle school level.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923901/forall-n-in-mathbb-nnx-in-mathbb-q-implies-x-in-mathbb-z-elementary-pro?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer: The problem can be reformulated as follow, let $\epsilon=\{a\}=a-\lfloor a \rfloor$ be the fractional part of the real number $a$:
$$\mbox{Given} \quad 0\leq \epsilon < 1, \quad n^\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q} ,\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies \epsilon =0 $$
One can show that $\epsilon$ can not be rational since for any prime number $p$ and positive integers $k < m$ such that $\gcd(k,m)=1$ we can easily show that $\sqrt[m]{p^k}$ is irrational using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic and same argument as in proving $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
The remaining cases are the most difficult to get "elementary proof" and those cases are when $\epsilon$ is irrational.