# Is it possible that $n^{\alpha}$ is rational for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 < \alpha <1$?

Tags: analysis

I think that is impossible, i.e., for each $\alpha \in (0,1)$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0^{\alpha}$ is irrational. Or equivalently, there is no $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $n^{\alpha}$ is rational for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But I can't prove it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, but I don't think there is any elementary proof ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2923901/127263) I ask about an elementary proof of an equivalent statement). One can prove this using the [six exponentials theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem) as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/378280/127263). Indeed, it is enough to just consider $2^\alpha,3^\alpha,5^\alpha$ to deduce that they can't all be rational for $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! With six exponentials theorem, this problem is quite easy!